# How to troubleshoot cause of read-only file system errors

Tags: xubuntu, filesystem, ssd, read-only

I'm running Xubuntu off of a fairly new Samsung EVO 250GB SSD.
Recently my root file system has been going into read-only mode and I need help troubleshooting it.

These are all the errors (and many more, basiclly nothing that needs to write to the file system works)

```
mktemp: failed to create file via template ‘/tmp/david/virtualenvwrapper-initialize-hook-XXXXXXXXXX’: Read-only file system
touch: cannot touch ‘’: No such file or directory
ERROR: virtualenvwrapper could not create a temporary file name.
zsh: locking failed for /home/david/.zhistory: read-only file system: reading anyway
```

Here are some dmesg logs:

```
[264394.925883] EXT4-fs error (device sda7): ext4_mb_free_metadata:4588: group 100, block 3305968:Block already on to-be-freed list
[264394.925952] EXT4-fs error (device sda7) in ext4_free_blocks:4879: Journal has aborted
[264394.925958] EXT4-fs error (device sda7) in ext4_reserve_inode_write:4752: Journal has aborted
[264394.926012] EXT4-fs error (device sda7): ext4_journal_check_start:56: Detected aborted journal
[264394.926061] EXT4-fs error (device sda7) in ext4_reserve_inode_write:4752: Journal has aborted
[264394.926104] EXT4-fs error (device sda7) in ext4_reserve_inode_write:4752: Journal has aborted
[264394.926146] EXT4-fs error (device sda7): ext4_journal_check_start:56: Detected aborted journal
[264394.926154] EXT4-fs error (device sda7) in ext4_ext_remove_space:3048: Journal has aborted
[264394.926201] EXT4-fs error (device sda7) in ext4_ext_truncate:4669: Journal has aborted
[264394.926251] EXT4-fs error (device sda7) in ext4_reserve_inode_write:4752: Journal has aborted
[264394.926292] EXT4-fs error (device sda7) in ext4_truncate:3648: Journal has aborted
[264394.926335] EXT4-fs error (device sda7) in ext4_reserve_inode_write:4752: Journal has aborted
[264483.167154] EXT4-fs error (device sda7): ext4_remount:4888: Abort forced by user
```

I can usually solve the problem by restarting a couple of times.

I need one of two things:

- Prove that the SSD is faulty so I can return it.
- Find the issue.

Also, I'm dual booting windows 10 on the SSD as well if that's relevant.

Comment: have the same issue with my Samsung EVO 250GB SSD. I've used it for a mongo database for 4 months.

Answer (score 0):

When I was having this problem my issue was that the dual boot of windows which had access to the same drive was not shutting down fully - despite clicking on shut-down it was going into a type of sleep which kept an edit lock over the disk.

`shutdown /s`

From windows command prompt does a proper shutdown - and there's a tutorial here about how to turn of the Fast Startup option here:

https://www.howtogeek.com/349114/shutting-down-doesnt-fully-shut-down-windows-10-but-restarting-it-does/